# Visual Studio Code - removing pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Simple question - but any steps on how to remove pylint from a Windows 10 machine with Python 3.5.2 installed.

I got an old version of pylint installed that's spellchecking on old Python 2 semantics and it's bugging the heck out of me when the squigglies show up in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 54):

Open the workspace settings file (select File > Preferences > Settings, then locate Python configuration) and edit this line like this:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false
```

then save the file.

Comment: If this doesn't work immediately, press Ctrl+Shift+P, type "Reload Window" and press enter.

Comment: Similarly in VSCode for OS X, navigate to Code > Preferences > Settings to configure this value.

Comment: Literally just doing `Reload Window` solved my issues.

Answer (score 32):

If you just want to disable `pylint` then the updated VSCode makes it much more easier.

> Just hit **CTRL + SHIFT + P > Select linter > Disabled Linter.**

Hope this helps future readers.

Comment: for me it was: [Ctrl + Shift + P] > Python: Enable Linting > [Enter] > selection list that shows "on" and "off"

Answer (score 10):

The question was how to remove python linter, not how to disable it.

In order to remove pylint open Powershell/cmd and type:

```
pip uninstall pylint
```

Answer (score 6):

If you still see the problem like "Missing class docstring Pylint(missing-class-docstring" after you tried the ways suggested in this page, it may because your VS Code installed the extension **Pylint**, you can hit CTRL + SHIFT + X to open your installed extension list, and disable it.

[image]

Comment: It worked for me other solutions didn't. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I have followed all instructions here, but even though pylint was disabled in the settings and in settings.json, window reloaded and everything, it still showed pylint errors instead of flake8, which I had selected and configured. It turned out I had an extension installed called "Linter" created by Nando Vieira which somehow started to overwrite the linting behaviour of Microsoft's "Python" extension. Disabling the "Linter" extension and reloading the window finally solved the problem.

Comment: In my case, I had to disable and re-enable pylace and python Microsoft extensions.

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem but it was fixed with this solution CTRL + SHIFT + P > Selecionar linter > Linter desabilitado.