# VS Code shows an error message at print statement in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, visual-studio-code, pylint

> I use VS Code Version 1.19.3 with Python 2.7 on Windows.

Recently pylint (code analyzer) shown an error message 
`"E1601:print statement used"`

But I don't know why! Can someone help me?

**The print statement is correct as per my knowledge!**

Is it a bug or a feature is missing?

Greetings niesel

[image]

Answer (score 14):

The warning originates from Pylint, which is a very helpful tool for a dynamic language with loose syntax like Python. Since you are programming in Python 2.x where print is perfectly valid, I suggest you put a file in the root of your repo named `.pylintrc` and use it to configure Pylint.

To disable the print warning and leave everything else to the default, enter these two lines in your `.pylintrc` file:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=print-statement
```

You will also need to tell Visual Studio Code to use your configuration file by opening your workspace *or* user settings and add this:

```
{
     "python.linting.enabled": true,
     "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
     "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
          "--rcfile=/path/to/.pylintrc"
     ]
}
```

**More options**

To get a good idea of available configuration options open a terminal/prompt and run this command to generate a sample configuration file:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > sample_pylintrc
```

Comment: You can also disable that message for a single file (e.g. some standalone script) with a comment placed anywhere near the top of your script:
`# pylint: disable=print-statement`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, that changing from print statement to print function doesn't help much. So it seems, that it is some bug in VS Code Python module (2018.1 (01 Feb 2018)), as after this update I've found the same problem in my VS Code within my old projects

[image: bug screenshot]

I've found reffered bug on their [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43024)

PS: vscode-python has changed pylint options since 2018.1. In order to return old behavior you may disable **python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers** option for the workspace or for the userspace.

Comment: Actually, it resulted in possible bug in pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1869

Comment: You're still using `print` as a statement here. You should `from __future__ import print_function` if you wish to use `print` as a function in 2.7

Answer (score 0):

it's not an error per-se, it's just PyLint complaining about those legacy statements. PyLint will also complain about missing spaces before commas, those kind of style errors.

PyLint is there to warn you about possible problems. Your code will break when running python 3, so it warns you before it happens.

Note that `print` is a statement in python 2.x (which explains the message), and became a *function* in python 3.x.

Fix it by changing to:

```
print("test")
```

Since it's not a `tuple`, it works fine and does exactly the same for all versions of python, and PyLint will stop complaining.

you can also get rid of PyLint altogether: [Windows 10 - Visual Studio Code - removing pylint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626429/windows-10-visual-studio-code-removing-pylint) (not sure if it's a good idea)