# Error using Alpha Vantage while following tutorial, - Pylint error

Tags: python, pandas, stock, alpha-vantage

I'm learning about the alpha vantage package, and I've have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJO9fKj3_u4 by Derrick Sherrill, but I have run into some problems.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.techindicators import TechIndicators
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

api_key = 'XXXX'

ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')
data_ts, meta_data_ts = ts.get_intraday(
symbol='MSFT', interval='1min', outputsize='full')

period = 60

ti = TechIndicators(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')
data_ti, meta_data_ti = ti.get_sma(
symbol='MSFT', interval='1min', time_period=period, series_type='close')

df1 = data_ti
df2 = data_ts['4. close'].iloc[period-1::]

df2.index = df1.index

total_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(total_df)
```

When defining the variable df2 I get a red underline and tells me:

`Sequence index is not an int, slice, or instance with __index__pylint(invalid-sequence-index)`

Although I'm not sure that's the problem.

I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to get a set of data, but thats not the case at the moment.

This is the full terminal message after trying to run the script:

```
  File "/Users/ludvighenriksen/Desktop/Code/api.py", line 15, in <module>
    data_ti, meta_data_ti = ti.get_sma(symbol='MSFT', interval='1',
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", line 218, in _format_wrapper
    call_response, data_key, meta_data_key = func(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", line 160, in _call_wrapper
    return self._handle_api_call(url), data_key, meta_data_key
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", line 337, in _handle_api_call
    raise ValueError(json_response["Error Message"])
ValueError: Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for SMA.
```

[image]

Hope you are able to help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try again? The pylint error from df2 isn't the issue. I was able to run your code with no issue. Were you not using MSFT as the symbol?

Comment: It still don't seem to work. Maybe there is something wrong with my installation. I'll add a screenshot to the question then you can see.

Comment: The picture is added now

Comment: Screenshot may help. Also, if you run `pip freeze` you should be able to see what version of alpha_vantage you're running too. Looks like you're on python 3.8 which should work fine. You should have installed 2.2.0 version of alpha_vantage.

Comment: The screenshot shows a different error than what you are reporting in your question. `data['close'].plot()` is that the actual error you are getting when you run this?

It also looks like you didn't save. Could you save and then run the code?

Comment: Probably, I have no idea what the error is because i just wanted to get an introduction by following step by step. The version of alpha vantage is 2.20

Comment: Do you have any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: It just ran the program and i got the data, but it is still showing the same errors. This is weird as f*ck

Comment: Could you update your screenshot please with the error and with a saved api.py file.

Comment: Done, as you can see, it still has errors - but at the same time it seems to be working

Comment: Great! Let me add an answer below (and please remove the API key from the pic!)

Comment: Done-Diego......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misunderstandings here.

The red line squiggle you see under df2 is a [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) error. Pylint is a form of [linting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) tool, which can often find parts of your code that will break, but it also find stylistic errors. A stylistic error is an error of how you write your code, it may not actually break the code. The error you got can be found [here](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html) from the pylint documentation.

You can disable this "code cleanness checker" a few ways. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626429/visual-studio-code-removing-pylint) or [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) for more information. 
Mac: Command+Shift+P > type "python: enable linting" > set "off"
Windows: CTRL+SHIFT+P > Select linter > Disabled Linter.

The original error you got seems to have been some user error from before, maybe you had the wrong symbol, but your output screenshot does not seem to have the reproduced error.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It means the world to me, that there are people in this world like you, ready to help, and take your time to learn others the skills that you have mastered. Keep going man! Ill take a look at the links, so that one day im as comfortable as you