# Useless info erros in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Something updated recently, and in my python files, vscode now shows over 100 infos. And puts tons of blue squiggly lines under my code. For example one of the infos is

> Exactly one space required around assignment pylint(bad-whitespace)

How can I disable these?

Also, here are some photos that show my problem.

[image]

[image]

I have tried putting

```
"python.linting.flake8Args": ["--ignore=C"]
```

in the setting of vscode, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40626429/3929826) pylint. But the best idea might be to fix you code.

Comment: if you like pylint you should change your code, or you could just switch to some other linter. my personal choice would be mypy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you are using pylint, you should take this to ignore the Convention type problem:

```
 "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=C"],
```

Comment: This works great. Also for future users make sure to save the settings.json file in vscode since it seems to not automatically save.

Answer (score 0):

Try a find replace with this Regex.

Find:

```
(\S+)\s*=\s*
```

Replace:

```
$1 =
```

There is one space at the end of replace. Adjust to take care of named parameters

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are wanting me to do.